# OpenID Connect (Google's Oauth) feature implemented in Swagger-UI?

Tags: swagger-ui

Does the current version of Swagger-UI (the UI specifically, not the OpenAPI specification) support OpenID Connect when it authorizes users?

My search on Google, Stackoverflow and the SmartBear sites did not provide a definitive answer.  With Swagger-UI having almost weekly build cycle, I thought I'd ask just in case I might have missed mention about it.

Comment: Do you mean [Google OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) specifically? Or do you mean [OpenID Connect Discovery](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/) (OIDC) where the clients are supposed to read the config from the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` file)?

Comment: I am embarassed to show my ignorance, but I thought the two were the same.  That is to say, I thought Google had its variant of OAuth which was called OpenID Connect.  On that basis, I was asking about Open ID Connect,  Helen.

Comment: Your two links were helpful. I suspect the correct answer to your question is Google OAuth now. I'be checking that out with the server development team later today.

Comment: The server team replied it is the former, Helen.  Google OAuth specifically. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Another assignment took priority.  It is still on a short todo list. Thanks for the reminder, though.